# OS VectorMap Local Layer Definition Files

Tags: qgis, style, ordnance-survey

Would anybody be so kind enough to share their QGIS QML-File for the following OS VectorMap Local layers? SLD file formats would work as well. Alternativly, where do you buy your OS VML data from? The site I got mine don't have the files I need yet.

- Boundary_Line
- Building_Area
- Building_Line
- Building_Text
- Countour_Line
- Height_Point
- Height_Text
- Landform_Area
- Landform_Line
- Misc_Text
- Point_Misc
- Road_Line
- Road_Text
- RoadCLine
- Settlement_Area
- Settlement_Line
- Vegetation_Area
- Water_Area
- Water_Line
- Water_Point
- Water_Text
- Woodland_Area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS provide all their [Style sheets on github](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/resources/carto-design/cartographic-stylesheets.html) so for [vector map local](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-Local-stylesheets/) you have QML or SLD available for use with [shapefiles](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-Local-stylesheets/tree/master/ESRI%20Shapefile%20stylesheets) or [gml](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-Local-stylesheets/tree/master/GML%20stylesheets).